# Custom Searcher - Blending of hits from different sources

Tags: vespa

We have a need for "Blending of hits from different sources", as per your documentation it is recommended to write a custom-searcher in JAVA. Is there a demo of this written somewhere on Github ? I wouldn't even know where to start :( I understand I can create search "chains" , preferably Asynchronous, and then blend results in JAVA before returning them...but then how would I handle paginations, limits...etc ? This all seems very complicated, for someone who doesn't even know JAVA that much. So, I am hoping someone has already written a demo for this ? Please ? Anyone ?

Thank you so much

EDIT to make my quesion clearer:

We are writing a search engine that fetches data from various websites. Some websites have 10mil indexable items, other websites only 100,000. When we present the results to end user, we want to include results from all our sources ( when match applies ). Let's say 10 results from each of the websites we crawl, so that they all get equal amount of attention on page. If we don't do custom blending, what happens is that the largest website with most items wins all our traffic.

I understand that we can send 10 separate queries to VESPA, and blend the results in our front end, but that seems very inefficient. Thus, the quesion of "Custome Searcher". Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

That documentation covers some very advanced use cases which you do not have. Are your sources different Vespa schemas or content clusters? If so Vespa will by default blend the hits returned from each according to their relevance scores so there's nothing you need to do.

The two other most common use-cases are:

- Some (or all) the data sources are external, so you need to write a Searcher component to fetch the external data and turn it into a Result.
- You want the data to be blended in some custom way (rather than by relevance score). If so you need to exclude the default blending Searcher (com.yahoo.prelude.searcher.BlendingSearcher) and write your own.

If you provide some more information about your use cases I can give you some code examples.

EDIT: Use grouping to solve the need explained under "EDIT" in the question:

- Create a "siteid" field when feeding (e.g in document processing).
- Use the grouping expression `all(group(siteid) each(max(10) output(summary())))`

See http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/grouping.html

Comment: Thank you Jon, I've edited my original post to answer your quesions. Also , the "different schema" is probably not an issue for us - we can make all sources to have same schema - if that's something that would make our lives easier. "external vs. internal sources" - I don't understand that question, but we keep all data inside Vespa..so I guess internal :) Thank you so much.

Comment: It seems to me like your use case is to group by site to limit the number of results per site? You can compute a siteid during document indexing and use  grouping to limit the number of results per unique siteid. See http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/grouping.html